# Sharelatex word count

Tags: sharelatex

Does sharelatex count words from the pdf document of the source file? If they do it from the source file, does that include the preamble for example?

Comment: Take a look here https://www.sharelatex.com/blog/2015/09/15/word-count.html and test it yourself...

Answer (score 5):

Very easy to test that the preamble is not included in the word count:

[image]